# python-binance: Get all orders, without specifying symbol

Tags: python, binance

Trying to fetch my Binance accounts order history with the `python-binance` module. There is an option to get all orders within one symbol ([see documentation](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/account.html#id7)):

```
orders = client.get_all_orders(symbol='BNBBTC', limit=10)
```

Bu the problem is I can't pass more than 1coin in the symbol parameter
How can I pass a list for the symbol parameter, I want to fetch more than 1 coins order history in a single function
as I'm trying to build a portfolio for my Binance account. Or is there another method to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to get all historical orders or trades without specifying the symbol in one call, even without the module `python-binance`.

There is an [ongoing discussion](https://dev.binance.vision/t/fetch-all-account-orders/279) on the Binance forum, requesting this feature.

---

As a workaround:

- If you know your ordered symbols: Use the function `get_all_orders()` multiple times for each symbol in a loop.
- If you don't know your ordered symbols: you could send a GET request for each symbol available at Binance (as mentioned in the discussion linked above). But be careful with the `rateLimits`.

Comment: yes, I could do the loop but. is it possible if I had a function to fetch all the ordered symbols and then somehow pass those results to the **get_all_orers()**. The issue for me I need to calculate profit or loss which depends on the order history,

Comment: @HemanthGirimath I know your struggle. I do the calculation (profit/loss etc.) on the fly and store them in a separate database.

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself the same thing. Well, a work around would be to iterate over all the tickers available in Binance looking for the ones we did traded in the past.

If you are working the free plan of the API, the best would be to setup a storage file or database and store all the result. Then you have to care about keeping with the changes from there.

Yeah, it is exactly how I am going to deal with this.

(edit) :
Sleep function will be needed to avoid more than 1200 queries per minute.

(example) :

```
def getAllTickers(self):

        # Get all available exchange tickers
        exchangeInfo = self.client.get_exchange_info()

        # Extract the tickers general info
        exchangeSymbols = []

        for i in exchangeInfo['symbols']:
            exchangeSymbols.append(i)

        return exchangeSymbols

            
    def getMyTrades(self, strSymbol):
        return self.client.get_my_trades(symbol=strSymbol)

    def getMyTradedTickers(self):

        tickers = self.getAllTickers()
        # Extract every ticker where trade happened
        traded = []
        for i in tickers:
            tickerTransactions = self.getMyTrades(i["symbol"])
            if tickerTransactions :
                traded.append(tickerTransactions)
                print(i["symbol"], " transactions available")
            else :
                print(i["symbol"], " has no transactions")
            self.time.sleep(0.1)
        
        return traded
```

**Srry for the code quality. Python is not my main coding language and im getting use to it.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. This is a good way of doing it but as I'm a beginner and I don't know much about databases. so what I'm doing is I'm storing the trade data for over a year in an excel file and then fetching the data I need from the file(downloading trade data from[link] (https://in.tradingview.com/chart/ website )). This seems to be very simple for me.

Comment: I don't think 0.1 seconds is enough for some calls... The 10-weight calls need 0.5 seconds between executions if run continuously.  In my implementation, I've built the weight into my request method, and when you call an endpoint, it remembers the earliest time the next request should be able to be called to respect the rate limits.  So for 10-weight calls, it sets now + (60 / 1200 * 10) seconds as the next execution, and if the next call occurs before that time lapses, it sleeps for the difference.  This keeps you from having to wait unconditionally in case you don't have subsequent calls.